save and load keras transformer model
i am still new to deep learning right now i follow this keras tutorial to make an translation model using transformer here the link. Everything works just fine but i have no idea how to save the model, currently i have this implementation
transformer.save("models/transformer.h5")

and load the model with this
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
    "models/transformer.h5",
    custom_objects={
        "PositionalEmbedding": PositionalEmbedding,
        "TransformerEncoder": TransformerEncoder,
        "TransformerDecoder": TransformerDecoder,
    },
)
new_model.summary()

i also attempt to save the vectorization and load it with pickle following this
but when i use the model outside the notebook the model is worsen, when i load the model in the same notebook it just fine (without reloading the vectorization)
can someone guide me how to correctly how to save this model?

Can you define 'worsen' - it produces bad outputs?  It doesn't work?  I would recommend using a modern format using .keras instead of .h5 - it is supported to work in TensorFlow 2.0 and will save your optimizer config and custom layers.
Save the model like this:
transformer.save("models/transformer.keras")

And load the model like this:
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
    "models/transformer.keras",
    custom_objects={
        "PositionalEmbedding": PositionalEmbedding,
        "TransformerEncoder": TransformerEncoder,
        "TransformerDecoder": TransformerDecoder,
    },
)

And the vectorization
vectorized_layer.save("models/vectorized_layer")
vectorized_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization.from_saved_model("models/vectorized_layer")

